# display a portion of text that is inbetween specified characters oracle sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Original data is this :

```
xy12j-ty75#pid
bvbn-8ffde#pid
gonw-5gt#pid
qertt-yytre#pid
```

i need to only display the data inbetween the '-' and '#' like this :

```
ty75
8ffde
5gt
yytre
```

i wrote 2 different codes that if put together (somehow) i think would work.

my code 1 (displays everything to the left of the '#':

```
SQL> select substr(pcode, 1, (instr (pcode, '#'))-1)
  2  from products ;
```

displays this:

```
----------------------------------------
xy12j-ty75
bvbn-8ffde
vb-5gt
skr-yytre
```

and my code 2 that displays everything to the right of the '-' :

```
SQL> select ltrim(pcode, (substr(pcode, 1, (instr(pcode, '-')))))
  2  from products ;
```

displays this:

```
----------------------------------------
ttg#pid
lbcx#pid
gonw#pid
ertt#pid
```

it is also important that I use the subsr and instr functions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your strings always match the pattern of your sample data, you may combine `instr` and `substr` in this way:

```
select substr(pCode,
              instr(pCode, '-') + 1,
              instr(pCode, '#') - instr(pCode, '-') -1 
             )
    from products
```

For example, this

```
with products(pCode) as (
    select 'xy12j-ty75#pid' from dual union all
    select 'bvbn-8ffde#pid' from dual union all
    select 'gonw-5gt#pid' from dual union all
    select 'qertt-yytre#pid' from dual
)
select substr(pCode, instr(pCode, '-')+1, instr(pCode, '#') - instr(pCode, '-')-1)
from products
```

gives:

```
ty75
8ffde
5gt
yytre
```

Here you use `instr` to start from the char just after the `'-'` and a combination of `instr` and `substr` to count the number of characters between the `'-'` and the `'#'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression

```
select regexp_substr(pcode, '(.*?-)(.*?)#',1,1,'',2) from products
```

e.g.

```
with products (pcode) as (
    select 'xy12j-ty75#pid' from dual union all
    select 'bvbn-8ffde#pid' from dual union all
    select 'gonw-5gt#pid' from dual union all
    select 'qertt-yytre#pid' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(pcode, '(.*?-)(.*?)#',1,1,'',2) from products
```

Comment: this does work, but in my situation, as stated in my op, it is important that I use the subsr and instr functions for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `replace` applying over `instr`&`substr` string operations :

```
select replace( substr(pcode, 1, (instr (pcode, '#'))-1), 
                substr(pcode, 1, (instr (pcode, '-'))) ) "Result Set"
  from products;

Result Set
----------
ty75
8ffde
5gt
yytre
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecf2bf/2)